# What is the range of R.id (min and max integer value) of any view

Tags: android, button, view, boolean, android-resources

I am creating an android app in which I want to create Boolean Array of size of maximum value of IDs so that I can uniquely store the changes on the buttons.

Suppose my button id is 102931, when user click on the button I will make change in the Boolean array's 102931th element so that later I can check the changed value in it.

Now My Question is

**What is the range of IDs(min-max) for any view?**

Comment: It's an integer, which means range is [-2.147.483.648; 2.147.483.647].

Comment: @azizbekian Here its mentioned that ids can't be negative numbers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849121/android-why-should-ids-of-views-should-be-positive-numbers

Comment: Sure, then you answered your question yourself.

Comment: @azizbekian It means that it range from 0 to max int value.
Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 7):

They can be positive integers, but also, ids generated at build time will have a value greater than `0x00FFFFFF`. If you look at `View.generateViewId()` you will see that dynamically generated ids are in range `1` to `0x00FFFFFF` inclusive. Above that, there are `R.id`'s ids.

The default id of a `View` is `View.NO_ID` which has value `-1`